# Asymptotically unbiasedness of estimator

Tags: self-study, unbiased-estimator

I am reffering to the formula given at 2:18 in following video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6i7mqDJICzQ

Can someone explain how he arrived from this:

$\bar{X}=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^Nx_{i}$

to:

$E(\bar{X})=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^NE(x_{i})$

The first formula is the average of values of $x_i$. The second formula should be the "average of averages", right? If $N$ is the sample size, how can second formula be true?

Comment: Linearity of expectation.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Could you please explain.

Comment: See your own comment below, I think you got it yourself already.

Answer (score 2):

$\bar X$ is a random variable but the denominator customarily would be $N$ rather than $N-1$. The asymptotics works either way. The second equation would follow by the linearity of the expectation as has already been mentioned.  Again the formula customarily would have $N$ in the denominator.  The $X_i$ represents a sequence of random variables. It may be easier to think about the special case when they are independent and identically distributed. Do not consider them as the actual sample values.

$E(X_i)$ is the population mean $\mu$. The second equation shows that the sample mean has the same expected value as the individual observations. That does not mean that a realization of the sample mean is always $\mu$.  Rather if you repeatedly generate samples and compute the sample mean, each time the arithmetic average of all these realizations will be close to $\mu$ and converge to $\mu$ as the number of repetitions gets large.

Comment: $N$ would be sample size? What do you mean when you say that $x_i$ should be considered as i.i.d. random values but not as actual sample values?

Comment: This is the key point that may be causing you confusion. I said that they represent a sequence of random variables with the same probability distribution.

Comment: Maybe an example will help.  Let X be a random variable with the distribution N(0,1) a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1.  X can take on any value on the real line.  X can take on the values when taking a sample.  The values tend to be close to 0 and the sample distribution should approximate the normal distribution. Expectation represents the average of the particular random variable.

Comment: You make many assumptions that are not necessary for the equation in the question to be true, Michael: the only reason to insist on $1/N$ instead of $1/(N-1)$ is your assumption of an unstated context and that the bar has a conventional meaning; there is no need for the $X_i$ to be independent; and they needn't have a common distribution.  The only necessary assumption is that all those expectations actually exist.

Comment: @whuber The OP is having trouble understanding the difference between a sample and a random variable.  The other two answers that are given fall into the same trap. The 1/N is necessary because otherwise E(X_bar) =N (mu)/(N-1) which is not equal to mu.  I realize that it is asymptotically unbiased.

Comment: I am not sure that the OP is really interested in the asymptotics. It is of course true that the linearity of expectation the X_i need not be independent. My objective was to give an answer with an example that would help the OP. I will edit the part about insisting on N in the denominator.

Comment: @whuber I think the changes I made will satisfy you.

Comment: @Michael Chernick I am aware that every estimate of X_bar comes from some distribution that is centered arround the real population value. And if if take the average of X-bar from all possible samples of size n we should get the real population parameter. In this case if the n is big enough the X_bar should converge to the real value E(X_bar) meaning the estimator is consistent. Is this correct?